# Error : [INS-20803] The optional tool named 'Oracle Configuration Manager Configuration' failed

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, failed-installation

at the time of installation of the oracle 12c i m facing this error

**Action - Refer to the logs or contact Oracle Support Services. As 'Oracle Configuration Manager Configuration' is an optional tool, it is safe to ignore this failure and proceed with the installation.**

any suggestions?